# javascript-want call function on the basis of element id

Tags: javascript

I have a list of hotels

```
<div id="hotel" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <h1>Hotels List</h1>
  <ul>
      <li onclick="getroom(i)">Hotel 1</li>
      <li onclick="getroom(i)">Hotel 2</li>
      <li onclick="getroom(i)">Hotel 3</li>
      <li onclick="getroom(i)">Hotel 4</li>
      <li onclick="getroom(i)">Hotel 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I have a function

```
function getroom(id)
{
    currentstat=id;

    im stuck here please help me
}
```

`currentstat` is a global variable.
I want one thing, when I click on hotel 2 the function returns me the rooms of hotel 2 instead of any hotel rooms. How can I get by setting any id.

Comment: This question says "javascript" but I don't see any.

Comment: killing :D ... please, show us, what is 'i' in getroom(), how does the getroom() look like? and what is the context of the app?

Comment: The random variable `i` looks like that would be an issue.... but who know from the lack of code.

Comment: now you can see javascript function which i have added yet..

Comment: how is list generated? Not hard to add attributes as list gets created

Answer (score 0):

You should have different i value based on that you can find the specific hotel rooms.

getroom(1)
getroom(2)
.
.

Comment: thats the problems where i stuck ...how can i get different values for 'i'??